Unable to Delete component although it is unpublished from broker
A component is unpublished from broker database, but while trying to delete the component, it keeps notifying the component is already published.

It's possible that the component was previously published with a different publishing target. In some cases, when publishing states aren't migrated to new target groups, issues like this can arise. I recommend reaching out to the RWS Tridion Sites support team for assistance. They can provide SQL scripts to rectify any broken publishing state in the CM database. Please refrain from attempting to fix this in the database yourself, as it could lead to unsupported.
